# Uncaught TypeError: p.addEventListener is not a function, how can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my JS code:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("submitButton");

p.addEventListener("click", () => {
    console.log("a");
});
```

Relevant piece of HTML code:

```
    input(type='submit' class='submitButton')
```

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting just one element to bind listener, then select specific element. In your case, it's first element:

```
var p = document.getElementsByClassName("submitButton")[0];
```

If you're targeting multiple elements, then you can bind listener using forEach like:

```
p.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('a');
}));
```